# How to register components inside other components in Livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire component rendering full page, but I'm trying to include a component in the middle of the view:

```
<div>
     <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-10 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
         @livewire('livewire.person.own-person-update')
     </div>
</div>
```

I have a component in this path:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Person;

use Livewire\Component;

class OwnPersonUpdate extends Component
{
     public function render()
     {
         return view('livewire.person.own-person-update');
     }
}
```

But I have the following error response in laravel:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atbaC.png)

Answer (score 3):

In the view you should call your component without the `livewire` as bellow:

```php
<div>
     <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-10 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
         @livewire('person.own-person-update')
     </div>
</div>
```